# Python3 list in function with Pyqt5 missing something

Tags: python-3.x, list, pyqt5

Hi I am trying to move the [MIT 6001](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/)  python3 assignement
number 2 into PyQt5.

Here my files:

main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDesktopWidget
import hangman005

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt_short"
wordlist = hangman005.load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME)

def main():
    def center(self):                     
        qr = self.frameGeometry()   
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()    
        qr.moveCenter(cp)    
        self.move(qr.topLeft())            
    class MainMenu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):                        
        def __init__(self):        
            super(MainMenu, self).__init__()            
            uic.loadUi('main_window2.ui', self)                                   
            self.centro = center(self)             
            self.centro                      
            self.show() 
            self.error_label.hide()
            self.groupBox.hide()
            self.word_to_guess.hide()
            self.available_guess.hide()
            self.vowels=('a','e','i','o','u')            
            self.newgame_button.clicked.connect(self.start2)           
        def closeEvent(self, event): #Your desired functionality here         
            close = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self,
                                         "QUIT",
                                         "Are you sure want to stop process?",
                                         QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes | QtWidgets.QMessageBox.No)
            if close == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.ignore()          
        def start2(self):
            self.error_label.hide()
            self.newgame_button.hide()
            self.groupBox.show()
            self.word_to_guess.show()
            self.available_guess.show()
            self.letters_guessed=[]
            self.max_guesses = 6
            self.secret_word = hangman005.choose_word(wordlist)
            self.secret_word_lenght=len(self.secret_word)
            self.secret_word=hangman005.splitt(self.secret_word)
            self.secret_word_print=('_ '*self.secret_word_lenght )
            self.word_to_guess.setText(self.secret_word_print )
            self.available_guess.setText(str(self.max_guesses) ) 
            self.letters=hangman005.splitt('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
            for i in self.letters:
                getattr(self, i).setEnabled(True)
            self.hangman_pyqt5()        

        def hangman_pyqt5(self):
            print(self.letters )
            for f in self.letters:
                print('lllllllllllllll : ' ,f)
                getattr(self, f).clicked.connect(lambda pippo, j=f: self.printo(j))

        def printo(self, i):
            print('oooooooooooooooooooooo :', i.lower())
            getattr(self, i).setEnabled(False)
            i=i.lower()
            self.word_to_guess.setText((' '.join(hangman005.get_guessed_word(self.secret_word, self.letters_guessed))).upper())
            self.available_guess.setText(str(self.max_guesses) )
            print(self.secret_word*5 )   
            if i not in hangman005.get_available_letters(self.letters_guessed):
                print('You can only choose in' , ' '.join(hangman005.get_available_letters(self.letters_guessed)))
                return

            elif i in hangman005.get_available_letters(self.letters_guessed):
                self.letters_guessed.append(i)
                print(' a che punto sei : ' , ' '.join(hangman005.get_guessed_word(self.secret_word, self.letters_guessed)))
                self.word_to_guess.setText((' '.join(hangman005.get_guessed_word(self.secret_word, self.letters_guessed)).upper()))
                self.available_guess.setText(str(self.max_guesses) )
                if i in self.secret_word:
                    print('GOOD !!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    print('\nyou still have ' , self.max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                else:
                    print('ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    if i in self.vowels:
                        self.max_guesses -= 2
                        self.available_guess.setText(str(self.max_guesses) )
                    else:
                        self.max_guesses -= 1
                        self.available_guess.setText(str(self.max_guesses) )
                        print('\nnow you have only' , self.max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

            if hangman005.is_word_guessed(self.secret_word, self.letters_guessed) == True:
                print('\nHAI VINTO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                total_score= self.max_guesses * len(list(set(self.secret_word)))                
                print('\nil tuo punteggio è : ' , total_score)
                return
            if self.max_guesses <= 0:
                print('\nHAI PERSO STUPIDA CAPRA !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                print('\n\n\n secret_word : ' , self.secret_word   )
                print('\nla parola era : ' , ''.join(self.secret_word), ' you moron !!')
                self.error_label.show()
#                self.newgame_button.show()
                self.groupBox.hide()            
                self.word_to_guess.setText((''.join(self.secret_word)).upper())
                self.available_guess.hide()
#                self.letters_guessed.clear()
#                self.letters_guessed=[]
                self.newgame_button.show()
                return





    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

#    sshFile="coffee.qss"
#    with open(sshFile,"r") as fh:
#        app.setStyleSheet(fh.read())
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    window=MainMenu()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()

#all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
#sum1 = summary.summarize(all_objects)# Prints out a summary of the large objects
#summary.print_(sum1)# Get references to certain types of objects such as dataframe

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

hangman005.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
import string

def load_words(WORDLIST_FILENAME):
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = line.split()
    print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.") 
    return wordlist

def choose_word(wordlist):    
    return random.choice(wordlist)

def splitt(word): 
    return [char for char in word]   

def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    prova =all(item in letters_guessed for item in secret_word )    
    print(' prova : ' , prova )
    return prova 
def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    print('\n\nsecret_word_split' , secret_word)
    print('letters_guessed', letters_guessed )
    results=[]
    for val in range(0,len(secret_word)):
            if secret_word[val] in letters_guessed:
                results.append(secret_word[val])
            else:
                results.append('_')
    print('\nresults : ' , ' '.join(results ))        
    return results


def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    entire_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    entire_letters_split=splitt(entire_letters)
    entire_letters_split = [x for x in entire_letters_split if x not in letters_guessed]
    return entire_letters_split 

def hangman(secret_word):
    letters_guessed=[]
    max_guesses = 6
    secret_word_lenght=len(secret_word)
    secret_word=splitt(secret_word)
    vowels=('a','e','i','o','u')

    print('\nWelcome to HANGMAN ;-) ')
    print('\nsecret_word_lenght : ' , secret_word_lenght  ) 
    print('\n'+' _ '*secret_word_lenght )
    print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

    while True:
        guess= input('\nmake your first choice : ' )
        if guess not in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                print('You can only choose in' , ' '.join(get_available_letters(letters_guessed)))
                continue
        if guess in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                letters_guessed.append(guess)
#                print('\nletters_guessed appended : ' , ' '.join(letters_guessed) )
#                max_guesses -= 1
                print(' a che punto sei : ' , ' '.join(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed)))
#                print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                if guess in secret_word:
                    print('GOOD !!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    print('\nyou still have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                else:
                    print('ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    if guess in vowels:
                        max_guesses -= 2
                    else:
                        max_guesses -= 1
                    print('\nnow you have only' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

        if is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed) == True:
            print('\nHAI VINTO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            total_score= max_guesses * len(list(set(secret_word)))

            print('\nil tuo punteggio è : ' , total_score)

            break
        if max_guesses <= 0:
            print('\nHAI PERSO STUPIDA CAPRA !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            print('\nla parola era : ' , ''.join(secret_word), ' you moron !!')
            break

def match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):

    if len(my_word) == len(other_word):

        for val in range(0,len(my_word)):
            if my_word[val] == '_':
#                print('OK')
                prova=True
            elif my_word[val] != '_' and my_word[val]==other_word[val]:
#                print('OK')
                prova=True
            else:
#                print('KO')
                prova=False
                break
    else:
#        print('DIFFERENT LENGHT')
        prova=False
    return prova


def show_possible_matches(my_word):

    x=0
    y=0
    for i in range(0,len(wordlist)):
        other_word=splitt(wordlist[i])
        if match_with_gaps(my_word, other_word):
            print(wordlist[i], end = ' ')
            x += 1
        else:
            y += 1
    print('\nparole trovate : ' , x)
    print('parole saltate : ' , y)
    print('parole totali  : ' , x+y)
    print('lenght wordlist :' , len(wordlist))
    return


end = ''
def hangman_with_hints(secret_word):


#    secret_word_lenght=len(secret_word)
#    print('secret_word_lenght : ' , secret_word_lenght  )

    letters_guessed=[]
    max_guesses = 6
    secret_word_lenght=len(secret_word)
    secret_word=splitt(secret_word)
    vowels=('a','e','i','o','u')

    print('\nWelcome to HANGMAN ;-) ')
    print('\nsecret_word_lenght : ' , secret_word_lenght  ) 
    print('\n use * for superhelp !!!! ')
    print('\n'+' _ '*secret_word_lenght )
    print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

    while True:
        guess= input('\nmake your choice : ' )
        if guess == '*' :
                print('ATTENZIONE SUPER BONUS !!!')
                my_word=(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed))
                show_possible_matches(my_word)
                continue
        if guess not in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                print('You can only choose in' , ' '.join(get_available_letters(letters_guessed)))
                continue
        if guess in get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
                letters_guessed.append(guess)
#                print('\nletters_guessed appended : ' , ' '.join(letters_guessed) )
#                max_guesses -= 1
                print(' a che punto sei : ' , ' '.join(get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed)))
#                print('\nyou have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                if guess in secret_word:
                    print('GOOD !!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    print('\nyou still have ' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')
                else:
                    print('ERRORE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
                    if guess in vowels:
                        max_guesses -= 2
                    else:
                        max_guesses -= 1
                    print('\nnow you have only' , max_guesses , ' guesses be carefull choosing')

        if is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed) == True:
            print('\nHAI VINTO !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            total_score= max_guesses * len(list(set(secret_word)))

            print('\nil tuo punteggio è : ' , total_score)

            break
        if max_guesses <= 0:
            print('\nHAI PERSO STUPIDA CAPRA !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
            print('\nla parola era : ' , ''.join(secret_word).upper(), ' you moron !!')
            break

#if __name__ == "__main__":
    # passui

    # To test part 2, comment out the pass line above and
    # uncomment the following two lines.

#    secret_word = choose_word(wordlist)
#    hangman(secret_word)

###############

    # To test part 3 re-comment out the above lines and 
    # uncomment the following two lines. 

#    secret_word = choose_word(wordlist)
#    hangman_with_hints(secret_word)
```

main_window2.ui :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>936</width>
    <height>686</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>HANGMAN</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">

</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLabel" name="word_to_guess">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>341</width>
      <height>91</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>18</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>word_to_guess</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>320</y>
      <width>821</width>
      <height>201</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
    background-color: #9de650;
}


QPushButton:hover{
    background-color: green;
}

</string>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="A">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="autoFillBackground">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>A</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="B">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>90</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>B</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="C">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>150</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>C</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="D">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>210</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>D</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="E">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>270</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>E</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="F">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>330</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>F</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="G">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>390</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>G</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="H">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>450</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>H</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="I">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>510</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>I</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="J">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>570</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>J</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="K">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>630</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>K</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="L">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>690</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>L</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="M">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>750</x>
       <y>50</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>M</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="N">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>N</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="O">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>90</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>O</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="P">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>150</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>P</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Q">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>210</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Q</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="R">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>270</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>R</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="S">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>330</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>S</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="T">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>390</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>T</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="U">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>450</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>U</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="V">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>510</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>V</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="W">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>570</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>W</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="X">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>630</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>X</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Y">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>690</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Y</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Z">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>750</x>
       <y>120</y>
       <width>41</width>
       <height>41</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Z</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="available_guess">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>120</x>
      <y>160</y>
      <width>141</width>
      <height>81</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>20</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
    background-color:  #b3ffff;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>TextLabel</string>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="newgame_button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>310</x>
      <y>550</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>71</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>18</pointsize>
      <weight>75</weight>
      <bold>true</bold>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>START NEW GAME</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="error_label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>170</x>
      <y>50</y>
      <width>541</width>
      <height>411</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
  background-image: url(:/img/hangman.jpg); background-position: center
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <zorder>error_label</zorder>
   <zorder>groupBox</zorder>
   <zorder>word_to_guess</zorder>
   <zorder>available_guess</zorder>
   <zorder>newgame_button</zorder>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>936</width>
     <height>29</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar">
   <property name="sizeGripEnabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="resource_hangman.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

words.txt_short :

```
sinew sings singe sinks sinus sioux sires sired siren sisal sissy sitar sites sited sixes sixty sixth sizes sized skate skeet skein skews skids skied skier skies stoic stoke stole stoma stomp stone stony stood stool stoop stops story stork storm stoup stout stove stows strap straw stray strew stria strip strop strum strut stubs stuck studs study stuff stump stuns stung stunk stunt style suave
```

So far I built only the error part; meaning I press the 'start new game' button; then pressing 6 wrong  letters (I mean using my 6 guesses without make the right guess, a wrong a,e,i,o,u, is minus 2 point all the rest is minus 1)  of the secret word I should get the entire word and the Start the game button again.
Problem is that if I dont put either a

`self.letters_guessed.clear()` in line 127 of main.py or

`self.letters_guessed=[]` or line 128 of main.py

I am not able to show the correct secret word on screen ( 'word_to_guess' QLabel) after the 6 failed attempts, and according to my print lines on terminal after the first wrong attempt it is like the last of the wrong letters I pressed has been pressed more than once (2 in second attempt, start new game second time; 3 in third attempt, start new game third time and so on..)

As soon as I uncomment lines 127 or 128 the program behaves as expected, giving the right word after using all the guessings available.

I cant figure out why its happening, moreover the

`self.letters_guessed=[]` in line 65 says the same thing of line 128 and line 127 just delete the list.

Why do I need this 127 or 128 line ?

line 65 is called with start2() after pressing the start_new_game QButton (line 45)
I know I should write a minimal reproducible error (behaviour in this case)
but this is so unclear to me, that I cannot figure out any. Sorry about that

Comment: think I kind of figured out need to disconnet something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added

```
i=i.upper()
getattr(self, i).disconnect()
```

or

```
getattr(self, i).clicked.disconnect()
```

at the end of the

def printo(self , i):

block in main.py